# Nested entities are not supported in r2dbcEntityTemplate.insert

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities as batch & batchDetailEntity. I try to insert records to my database postgresql using spring boot reactor r2dbcEntityTemplate.insert() & I am getting error like Nested entities are not supported.

My code
[image]

Error
[image]

Comment: please do not upload code as image

Comment: Can you explain as why was the `insert(Mono.just(batchDetailEntity)` was needed? Instead of just `insert(batchDetailEntity)`.

Comment: Initially it was like that but having the same error & the r2dbcEntityTemplate.insert() takes Mono object so just modify like that but no luck.

Comment: insert(batchDetailEntity) worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `insert(Mono.just(batchDetailEntity))`
put `insert(batchDetailEntity)` It may work for you.